# How can I allow members to access and edit profile page only?

Tags: admin-on-rest

I've created an admin dashboard for administrating members. As an admin I can login in do everything.

I need also to allow these members (regular users) to login, be redirected to their profile page and be able to edit a subset of their properties.

I've searched through the documentation but have been unable to figure how best to accomplish this.

Is there a standard way, and if there is how can do this?

Answer (score 1):

All what you need to manage user permissions on your dashboard is available on the [Authorization section of the documentation](https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/Authorization.html).

Firstly, at the authentication step, you have to [set the current user permission](https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/Authorization.html#configuring-the-auth-client) (basically a string of your choices, given by the API and/or stored inside the local storage for example: `user`, `admin`, `user_X`, etc):

```
if (type === AUTH_GET_PERMISSIONS) {
    const { role, id } = params;
    return Promise.resolve(`${role}_${id}`);
}
```

Then, you can [check this permission inside your resource declaration](https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/Authorization.html#restricting-access-to-fields-and-inputs):

```
export const UserEdit = ({ ...props }) =>
    <Edit title={<UserTitle />} {...props}>
        {permissions =>
            <TabbedForm defaultValue={{ role: 'user' }}>
                <FormTab label="user.form.summary">
                    <DisabledInput source="id" />
                    {permissions === `user_${props.record.id}` &&
                        <TextInput source="name" validate={required} />
                    }
                </FormTab>
            </TabbedForm>}
    </Edit>;
```

And you can also [restrict an entire resource to administrators](https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/Authorization.html#restricting-access-to-resources-or-views):

```
<Admin
    restClient={restClient}
    authClient={authClient}
>
    {permissions => [
        // Restrict access to the remove view to admin only
        <Resource
            name="customers"
            list={UserList}
            edit={UserEdit}
            remove={permissions.startsWith('admin') ? UserDelete : null}
        />,
        // Only include the categories resource for admin users
        permissions.startsWith('admin')
            ? <Resource name="categories" list={CategoryList} edit={CategoryEdit} />
            : null,
    ]}
</Admin>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also try to use my ra-component-factory that tackles those problems in a very elegant way: https://github.com/zifnab87/ra-component-factory it is now listed in contributions of admin-on-rest (https://github.com/marmelab/admin-on-rest/blob/master/docs/Ecosystem.md)

Here is the general skeleton of configuration - it helps you set fields as not visible or read-only, menu-item visibility, action button visibility and even tab arrangement per role and per action.

```
export default {
    props: {
        id: {
            input: (<TextInput source="id"/>),
            field: (<TextField source="id"/>),
        },
        name: {
            input: (<TextInput label="Name" source="name"/>),
            field: (<TextField label="Name" source="name"/>),
        },
        date: {
            input: (<DateInput source="date" parse={dateParser} label="Post Date"/>),
            field: (<DateField source="date" type="date" label="Post Date"/>),
        },
        dateGte: { //date Greater than equal
            input: (<DateInput source="dateGte" parse={dateParser} label="Date from"/>),
        },
        dateLte: { // date Less than equal
            input: (<DateInput source="dateLte" parse={dateParser} label="Date to"/>),
        },
        author: {
            input: <ReferenceInput label="Author" source="author" reference="authors" allowEmpty>
                      <SelectInput optionText="name" translate={false}/>
                   </ReferenceInput>,
            field: <ReferenceField label="Author" source="author" reference="authors" sortable={false} linkType={false} allowEmpty={true}>
                      <ChipField source="name"/>
                    </ReferenceField>
        },
    },

    role1: {
        create: {
            props: ["name", "author", "date"],
            action: true
        },
        edit: {
            props: ["_id", "name", "author", "date"],
            action: true
        },
        list: {
            props: ["id", "name", "author", "date"],
            action: true
        },
        filter: {
            props: ["q", "id", "author", "dateGte", "dateLte"],
            action: true
        },
        show: {
            props: ["id", "name", "author"],
            action: true
        },
        search: {
            action: true
        },
        delete: {
            action: true
        },

    },
    role2: {
        create: {
            props: [],
            action: false
        },
        edit: {
            props: [],
            action: false
        },
        list: {
            props: ["id", "name", "author", "date"],
            action: false
        },
        filter: {
            props: ["q", "id", "author", "dateGte", "dateLte"],
            action: true
        },
        show: {
            props: ["id", "name", "author"],
            action: true
        },
        search: {
            action: true
        },
        delete: {
            action: false
        },
    }
}
```